# Extend datepicker to start with dropdown using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement to display Datepicker with Dropdown as a single control, I have tried many samples available on the internet but they do not work for me.

My base code is given below with style in which I have to merge them.

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select name="Year" class="form-control" ng-model="Year" required>
                <option>2016</option>
                <option>2015</option>
                <option>2014</option>
            </select>
            <div ng-messages="form.formValidate.select.$error" ng-if="form.formValidate.$submitted" class="text-danger"><span ng-message="required">This field is required</span></div>
            <div class="ui-datepicker shadow-clear">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="date" required="" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><em class="ion-calendar"></em></button>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <div ng-messages="form.formValidate.date.$error" ng-if="form.formValidate.$submitted" class="text-danger"><span ng-message="required">This field is required</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Opps! I missed mentioning that both controls should be side by side as displayed in below image.

[image]

**Edit2**

http://www.bootply.com/Tftcr9VVrH

Comment: Could you set up a plunker?  It would be easier to help you if you did.   Thanks.

Comment: @jbrown link added.. they do not come side by side in there.

Comment: ok, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the elements in a div with class="form-inline" and put each group of elements into a div with class="form-group".  I forked your bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/EfqFdR0r41)

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Year">Date</label>
      <select name="Year" class="form-control" required="" ng-model="Year">
        <option>2016</option>
        <option>2015</option>
        <option>2014</option>
      </select>
      <div class="text-danger" ng-if="form.formValidate.$submitted" ng-messages="form.formValidate.select.$error"><span ng-message="required">This field is required</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="ui-datepicker shadow-clear">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="date" class="form-control" required="" type="text">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></em></button>
           </span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-danger" ng-if="form.formValidate.$submitted" ng-messages="form.formValidate.date.$error"><span ng-message="required">This field is required</span></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they should be inline as shown in the image, example http://www.bootply.com/PcRgYt3J9C.

Comment: They are in a single line but I now see you wanted inline.  Here's a new fork http://www.bootply.com/EfqFdR0r41  Not sure I've got exactly what you're looking for but close

Comment: Perhaps there's an alternative to class="input-group" that would tighten things up.  Check the Bootstrap CSS docs under form-inline

Comment: Thank you but the solution does not meet my requirement I want them merged so they look like single control.

Comment: Ok. I would restate your question with that detail since appearing as a single control is different than a single line or inline as is stated in your question.

Comment: Have updated the question, does that make sense now?

Comment: Yea that seems a better explanation of what you're looking for.